# Unable to Load Built in Dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to load the catsM dataset, but continue to get this error. I've tried the basics, restarting Rstudio, re-installing the package, etc., but continue to get this error.

> install.packages("boot")

```
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/becky/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
```

(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

```
   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/boot_1.3-25.zip'
   Content type 'application/zip' length 643617 bytes (628 KB)
```

downloaded 628 KB

```
   package ‘boot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

    The downloaded binary packages are in
       C:\Users\becky\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgHPMII\downloaded_packages
    > library(boot)
    > datasets:catsM
    Error: object 'datasets' not found
```

[image]

Comment: Run `data(catsM)`